# Eclipse error for mobile automation script - Appium io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException - Appium server version 2.0

Tags: node.js, android-studio, npm, appium, appium-android

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
null
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass ConfigureAppium
io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: **The main Appium script does not exist at '\usr\local\lib\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js'
at** io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.validatePath(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.loadPathToMainScript(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:294)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:361)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:444)
at org.rahulshettyacademy.utils.AppiumUtils.startAppiumServer(AppiumUtils.java:55)
at org.rahulshettyacademy.TestUtils.AndroidBaseTest.ConfigureAppium(AndroidBaseTest.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.rahulshettyacademy.TestUtils.AndroidBaseTest.tearDown(AndroidBaseTest.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:214)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod preSetup
SKIPPED: FillForm_ErrorValidation
io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: The main Appium script does not exist at '\usr\local\lib\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js'
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.validatePath(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.loadPathToMainScript(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:294)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:361)
at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:444)
at org.rahulshettyacademy.utils.AppiumUtils.startAppiumServer(AppiumUtils.java:55)
at org.rahulshettyacademy.TestUtils.AndroidBaseTest.ConfigureAppium(AndroidBaseTest.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 1

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 1